# Google Scripts Youtube Search RSS Generator

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, rss

I am using the common script to create custom RSS feeds of youtube searches. I wanted to add an image to the feed but alas, my little brain can't seem to figure this out. I've tried off and on for the last year. Please help!

```
function getSearchRSS(query){
  let results = YouTube.Search.list('id, snippet', {
    q: query,
    maxResults: 50,
    order: 'date'
  });
  
  let encoded_query = encodeURIComponent(query)
  let rss_url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?" + encoded_query;

  let channel = XmlService.createElement("channel")
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement("title").addContent(XmlService.createText("Youtube Search RSS Feed: " + query)))
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement("link").addContent(XmlService.createText("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + encoded_query)))
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement("description").addContent(XmlService.createText("Youtube Search RSS feed for search query '" + query + "' updated on " + (new Date()))))
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement("image").addContent(XmlService.createElement("image")
    .addContent(XmlService.createElement("link", XmlService.getNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")).setAttribute("rel", "self").setAttribute("href", rss_url));
  
  for(let i = 0; i < results.items.length; ++i){
    let video = results.items[i];
    let yt_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video.id.videoId;
    channel.addContent(XmlService.createElement("item")
      .addContent(
        XmlService.createElement("title").addContent(XmlService.createText(video.snippet.title))
      ).addContent(
        XmlService.createElement("link").addContent(XmlService.createText(yt_url))
      ).addContent(
        XmlService.createElement("thumbnail").addContent(XmlService.createText(video.snippet.thumbnails.default))
      ).addContent(
        XmlService.createElement("description").addContent(XmlService.createText(video.snippet.description))
      ).addContent(
        XmlService.createElement("pubDate").addContent(XmlService.createText(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(video.snippet.publishedAt), "EDT", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")))
      ).addContent(
        XmlService.createElement("guid").addContent(XmlService.createText(yt_url))
      ))
  }
  
  
  return XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(XmlService.createDocument(
        XmlService.createElement("rss").setAttribute("version", "2.0").addContent(channel)
      ));
}

function doGet(req) {
  let query = decodeURIComponent(req.queryString);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(getSearchRSS(query))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS)
}
```

This part is where I think i need to create an instance of some sort of image element but I cannot figure it out

```
addContent(XmlService.createElement("image").addContent(XmlService.createElement("image")
```

And this part to display it.

```
XmlService.createElement("image").addContent(XmlService.createText(video.snippet.thumbnails.default))
  ).addContent(
```

I enter this url as my RSS feed location

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxeBHDnQeBM_345ffgh5Ta1Rfx4zNDCi0iPITuWXIxr7voJIlx-/exec?the batman trailer reaction
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your script, can you provide the sample value of `query` and the value returned from `getSearchRSS(query)` you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike For reference, the original script I'm referencing:
https://gist.github.com/JuniorJPDJ/aa26d4c61bc1e78af039e9a17bc17907

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about the values of `query` and the value returned from `getSearchRSS(query)` you expect.

Comment: @KiloJKilo in the line where you're setting the thumbnail should be: `thumbnails.default.url`.